# How to apply blur to the whole body except navigation?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to apply blur to the entire page except the navigation menu when it's displayed.

I am using Bootstrap 4, and I have noticed that when I click on the button the class .show is applied to .navbar-collapse.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper-navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light container" data-nav-status="toggle">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler minus collapsed hidden-md-up" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="">
                <ul> ... </ul>
            </div>

        </nav><!-- .site-navigation -->
</div><!-- .wrapper-navbar end -->
```

And this is what I tried to do with CSS:

```
.blur-body >:not(#wrapper-navbar){
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

and JQuery:

```
$('.navbar-toggler').click(function (){
  if ( $('.navbar-collapse').hasClass('show') ) {
    $('body').addClass('blur-body');
  }
  else {
    $('body').removeClass('blur-body');
  }

})
```

Unfortunately this works just the opposite, at the first click (when I open the menu) it does not do anything, and when I close it, it applies the blur. I don't I understand why.

Some help? Or another different approach?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but what will happen if you add `if( ! $('.navbar-collapse').hasClass('show')) ...`

Comment: Yes, it works... but that makes me think that I'm not giving it the right approach ..

Comment: Take a look at the events that bootstrap is providing you for dropdowns. Much more reliable, and that's kind of what they're there for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap provides you with [**events**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#events) you can hook into. Specifically, when you do your navbar, you're using #navbarNavDropdown as a dropdown. As such, it gets those events. Use them as your triggers to cause the behavior you want:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#navbarNavDropdown').on("show.bs.collapse", function() {
    $("body").addClass("blur-body")
  }).on("hide.bs.collapse", function() {
    $("body").removeClass("blur-body");
  });
})
```

```css
.blur-body >:not(#wrapper-navbar) {
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="wrapper-navbar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light container" data-nav-status="toggle">

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler minus collapsed hidden-md-up" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="">
      <ul>
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
        <li>Last</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>
  <!-- .site-navigation -->
</div>
<!-- .wrapper-navbar end -->
<div class='content-pane'>
  <p>Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

  <p>Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper
    sit amet ligula. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

  <p>Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper
    sit amet ligula. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

  <p>Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper
    sit amet ligula. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

  <p>Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper
    sit amet ligula. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help. ;)